# How can I change path as root dir (PHP / Apache )?

Tags: php, apache

Nowadays I use path to file (in DB) like this

"/files/person_1/awatar.png"  - it works , file_get_content ("/files/person_1/awatar.png") = true  - is ok!

But now I changed my web server and ... In PHP I can see "directory not found exception"

Path on server: /var/www/public_html/new_service_xxxxx/files/awatar.png
In PHP I have "/" as first character, I don't want to change it.

What I should change ?

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName test.new_service_xxxxx.pl
    ServerAlias www.new_service_xxxxx.pl
    DocumentRoot /var/www/public_html/new_service_xxxxx


    <Directory /var/www/public_html/new_service_xxxxxk>
        Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
        AllowOverride All
        Require all granted
    </Directory>

    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined

    <IfModule mod_dir.c>
        DirectoryIndex index.php index.pl index.cgi index.html index.xhtml index.htm index.php5
    </IfModule>

</VirtualHost>
```

Comment: _"In PHP I have "/" as first character, I don't want to change it."_ - Your Apache config has nothing to do with PHP's `file_get_contents()`. Apache only handle HTTP requests (URL's) while `file_get_contents()` expects an internal file system path. If you still want to have the `/` in the beginning of your saved files, you need to prepend the absolute path, something like: `file_get_contents(__DIR__ . '/files/awatar.png')`. `__DIR__` will return the absolute path to the file it's written in.

Comment: You also say that the DB has `/files/person_1/awatar.png`, while showing us that the file is now in `files/awatar.png` (without the `person_1`). Is that correct or is it a typo in the question? In general, I would recommend not storing paths in the database. It's usually better to store the path in some config and just prepend it to the image name. Then you only need to change the path in the config if you change the location of the files.

Answer (score 1):

Go to the following locations and change the root folder, into a local folder in your Desktop.

```
   a) /etc/apache2/sites-available/000-default.conf
         Change "DocumentRoot /var/www/html"

   b) /etc/apache2/apache2.conf
         Find "<Directory /var/www/html/>
                 Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
                 AllowOverride None
                 Require all granted
               </Directory>"
         And change "/var/www/html"
```

I hope it helps.